# Is there a way to make Doctrine return different classes of one hierarchy after single find() call

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

I am struggling to solve one problem and want to ask your advise.

Here is simplified description.

In my system I have a list of statuses. User can perform some actions with it so I ended with [this kind of structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTsqg.png) (sorry, SO doesn't allow me to attach images yet). As you can see to keep my model DRY I've split it to some classes. `Status` and `ConfigurableStatus` are **abstract** classes (forgot to add this to diagram). `FirstStatus`, `CustomStatus` and `LastStatus` are **final** classes. I've added some simple behaviors to diagram but I think I will have more behaviors. However `FirstStatus` and `LastStatus` classes still have no own behaviors, only inherited, and I don't know if they would.

I also have a class that represents a list of statuses. We can have only one instance of `FirstStatus` and one instance of `LastStatus` per list. `FirstStatus` is always at the beginning of the list and `LastStatus` is always at the end. `CustomStatus` instances located somewhere in between. Statuses order **IS** important.

`FirstStatus` and `LastStatus` can't be created using `__construct()` or any other mechanisms and also can't be deleted. But `CustomStatus` could be created by user and deleted.

One more thing. Now all data for this status classes is located in single DB table. I am thinking of DB normalization but after that I think I will have ability to represent data as single table using MySQL View(s). I have `type` column to represent status type (first/last/custom).

## So the question is

Is there any way I can force Doctrine to return list of different statuses using `$entityManager->getRepository(Status::class)->findBy([], ['list_id' => 10]);`? So the returned array will have one `FirstStatus`, any number of `CustomStatus` and one `LastStatus`. Is it possible?

I was thinking about custom repository with `fetchList()` method, where I can implement it somehow. Something like this:

```
class StatusRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function fetchList(): StatusesList
    {
        $firstStatus = $this->_em
            ->getRepository(FirstStatus::class)
            ->findBy([], ['list_id' => 10, 'type' => 1]);
        // $customStatuses retrieval code
        // $lastStatus retrieval code

        return new StatusesList($firstStatus, $customStatuses, $lastStatus);
    }

    public function save(StatusesList $list): void
    {
        // Some saving code
    }
}
```

`StatusesList` class is important because it also encapsulates some logic. But this class is not always needed.

I think this will work fine if I need to fetch whole collection, however when I need to fetch concrete status by ID this will not work as I wish because I need to know proper entity type to pass to `getRepository()` method. In this case I think I can work with higher level `StatusesList` and fetch whole collection every time because DB performance is pretty good now, caching is enabled and etc., but this code is used in many places in app so its hard to predict how it will behave under load.

Another advantage is that I can use type to implement one of business rules: only custom statuses can be removed or added. So in repository implementation I would like to have a couple of methods like:

```
public function add(CustomStatus $status): void { // Some code }
public function delete(CustomStatus $status): void { // Some code }
```

But I think it will be harder (and code will be less clear) to implement with `StatusesList` since it located in my domain level.

## If there is no way to achieve what I want

I was thinking about creating single `final class Status` that will contain all properties from DB and every desired behavior. After that I will create hierarchy similar to hierarchy I [mentioned before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTsqg.png) that will be based only on interfaces. Then I can write custom repository class and e.g. add methods like `getOne(StatusId $id): FirstStatusInterface|CustomStatusUnterface|LastStatusInterface`. This `Status` class will implement all that interfaces (or last child of a tree, will see) so then I can fetch it from EntityManager and return in my methods.

Also I was thinking about single `Status` entity without interfaces. Then I need to check invariants using `$type` property which I think is not proper solution of my problem. Also this can cause a lot of checks like `if ($this->type->equals(Type::last())) { /** Do something */ }` which I really don't want to do. And even more, in this case repository will have `delete(Status $status)` method so I can't really encapsulate deletion restriction about which I wrote before, repository implementation will contain that `if (...) {}` check and this means that my business logic now also located in infrastructure level which I don't want.